# Using redux in my react app is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to react and trying to use redux in my code.
I have installed redux and react-redux by using below command:

```
 npm install --save redux react-redux
```

While importing refrence to redux store  in App.js file:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'

ReactDOM.render(
  
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    
    <App />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  
  
  document.getElementById('root')
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I am getting this error in browser :

Error in browser :

**Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './redux/store' in 'D:\Acumen\Hermes\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed**

does Any thing else is required?

Comment: You need to configure the store, you just copy/pasted some code from the web.

Comment: I am following steps from here:

https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#providing-the-store

Comment: The problem is in `./redux/store` please show us the code inside this file

Comment: Here is an codesandbox example from the documentation that I think OP is referencing https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo?file=/src/index.js

Comment: The codesandbox example is working fine.

Comment: I got error in my code, @HassanAzzam you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: So did you fix the issue ?

Comment: yes,its fixed now. I have compared with code  on codesandbox.